# Switching dual monitor setup, PC always tries to use second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, switch

I've got 2 monitors on my desk, and a Macbook for work. What I want to have is for my PC to always use 1 of the monitors, but that the second monitor I can alternate between my Macbook and my PC based on if I'm using it for personal or work.

I already had a [switcher](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00K2O556I/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and the basic setup of it works fine, I can alternate between the display for the Mac and the PC, but the problem is that the PC always seems to think there are 2 monitors available to it, so I can move my mouse or any dialogue boxes etc into where my PC thinks my second monitor is, even though it's currently showing my Macbook.

I realise anyone who is able to help will probably need specifics, so let me know what you need to know and I'll try to get the specifics

Comment: Yes, the whole idea is that the other device always thinks it has an output, which it does, just not one that you can see right now. That's how these things are designed. Otherwise anything on the second display would suddenly jump back to the main display… which is known to irritate people ;)

Comment: I suppose now I think about the setup it makes sense, the computer still thinks it's feeding out an HDMI output, but the Macbook sems to understand, but I'm wondering if that's because it's a laptop and understands an extra monitor better??